# ul li submenu show onclick using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, menu

1. I have some problem using my navigation menus. I need my navigation menus to display on-click. when i click on any menu with sub menu in it, it should display with its sub-menus, and remain displayed until i again click on this menu to be closed.
2. After this when i click on another menu with sub menu in it, it should also display with all its menu list and will be remain displayed until i again click on this menu to be closed.
3. I need that when i click on second menu list i.e (point number 2) , the previous sub menus list (i.e. point no. 1) should not hide and remain displayed with second sub menu list also i.e. both  sub menus lists will displayed at the same time.
4. When i click on one of the any menus list , it should hide only it's sub menus list and should not hide other sub menus list.

Thanks and regards.

---

I am sorry , i didn't mean like that.

Here is my code i am using :-

Jquery code   :-

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

      $("#nav li").click(function(){

         $(this).addClass("selected"); 

      }); 


      $("#nav li").click(function(){

        $("ul.sub-menu").toggleClass("open");

      }); 


      $("#nav li ul li").click(function(){

      $("ul.sub-menu").toggleClass("open"); 

      });

});

</script>
```

Comment: Are you trying to order us to make your project complete? Please post the code that you've tried yet.

Answer (score 1):

[FIDDLE FOR TOGGLE MENU](http://jsfiddle.net/Husen/gvmRX/25/)

So, here is the code:

HTML :

```
<div id="headermenu" class="click-nav">
  <ul class="no-js">
    <li id=""><a href="#">menu1</a></li>
    <li id=""><a class="have-second-level-menu" href="#">menu2</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li ><a class="have-third-level-menu" href="#">submenu1></a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">submenu.1 </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">submenu.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">submenu.3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">submenu.4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">submenu4</a></li>
        <li ><a class="have-third-level-menu" href="#">submenu1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">submenu7</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the Jquery for it:

```
$(function () {
  $('.click-nav .no-js .have-second-level-menu').click(function(e) {
     $(this).closest('li').find('.sub-menu').slideToggle(200);
    $('.clicker').toggleClass('active');
    e.stopPropagation();
  });

  $('.have-third-level-menu').click(function(e) {
      $(this).closest('li').find('ul').slideToggle(200);
    $('.clicker').toggleClass('active');
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
#headermenu {
    width: 90%;
    height: 20%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-bottom: .5%;
}
#headermenu ul ul {
    display: none;
}
/*#headermenu ul li:hover > ul {
        display: block !important;
    }*/
#headermenu ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-table;
}
#headermenu ul li {
    width: 100px;
    height: 45px;
    float: left;
    left: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: century gothic;
    background-color: #fef3e2;
}
#headermenu ul li:hover {
    background: #feaa38;
}
#headermenu ul li:hover a {
    color: #ffffff;
}
#headermenu ul li a {
    color: #feaa38;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
#headermenu ul ul {
    border-radius: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
}
#headermenu ul ul li {
    float: none;
    background: #b0c7bd;
    position: relative;
}
#headermenu ul ul li:hover {
    background: #aea7a0;
}
#headermenu ul ul li a {
    color: #ffffff;
}
#headermenu ul ul li a:hover {
    background: #aea7a0;
}
#headermenu ul ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
}
#headermenu:active ul ul {
    display: none;
}
```